# Is there a way to import .html file from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, cloudflare

I have the following import statements in my Cloudflare Worker project, to import a html file as a string constant :

```
import userAgentJsch from './userAgentJsch';
import { parse } from 'cookie';
import test from '.test.html';
```

It fails with the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.test.html' in

I was reading about needing to configure my *webpack.config.js* file, but I don't have such a file.

Can you please help? I just want to keep my html file separated from the js files, but I can't find a solution I can understand.

Comment: What's wrong with `fs.readFile`? If you don't know basic node.js stuff, then building on cloudflare is going to be over your head: the documentation is going to expect you to know things you don't know, and is just going to confuse you. Go do some basic node tutorials first. Gotta learn to walk before you learn to run, ya know.

Comment: I actually do know, it just that nothing worked :D. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

View folder structure is used for rendering templates no doubts

to read files in nodejs use this :

```
const fs = require("fs");
const files = fs.readFileSync("new.html");
```

and to import

```
var htmlContent = require('path/to/html/file.html');
```